# How can I run an OSX El Capitan Box under Vagrant?

Tags: macos, vagrant, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to get an OSX (ideally El Capitan) box set up under vagrant.  My host OS is El Capitan 10.11.6 (15G31).

Here's what I've tried so far

```
vagrant init
vagrant box add jhcook/osx-elcapitan-10.11
# edit vagrant init such that config.vm.box = "jhcook/osx-elcapitan-10.11"
vagrant up
```

However, I obtain the following error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'jhcook/osx-elcapitan-10.11'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'jhcook/osx-elcapitan-10.11' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: ratatouille_default_1471905801413_58611
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "e1aafdeb-650b-4b94-89cf-4ef39e22e7f6", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Implementation of the USB 2.0 controller not found!
VBoxManage: error: Because the USB 2.0 controller state is part of the saved VM state, the VM cannot be started. To fix this problem, either install the 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack' or disable USB 2.0 support in the VM settings.
VBoxManage: error: Note! This error could also mean that an incompatible version of the 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack' is installed (VERR_NOT_FOUND)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

What am I doing wrong?

How can I disable USB 2.0 support?

**Edit**:  Those voting to close, could you please tell me what the problem is?  I'm happy to correct it.

Comment: Have you tired fixing the error? "Because the USB 2.0 controller state is part of the saved VM state, the VM cannot be started. To fix this problem, either install the 'Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack' or disable USB 2.0 support in the VM settings."

Answer (score 3):

Okay, it was really simple.  I'm chalking this up to inexperience with Vagrant on my part.

Adding the following lines to the `Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|` block has solved the problem (thanks @TomMillard):

```
  # disable USB 2.0
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usb", "off"]
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usbehci", "off"]
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the USB port on the settings.
[image][image]